# Bootstrap input field doesn't look right in some cases

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, input, browser

I'm quite new here. In this simple bootstrap site, I have an input field with a label in front of it. It looks fine in my browser with default value 1.00, and it's responsive when I resize my browser. However that input filed becomes very small when I accessed the site through some other people's computers. The default value also disappeared. Is there anything wrong with how I defined this field? Many thanks in advance!

```
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">   
       <div class="input-group">
           <span class="text-center input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon2">Amount</span>
           <input class="form-control" type="text" id="amount" aria-describedby="sizing-addon1" value="1.00">
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You are using Bootstrap CDN/ a file hosted on a server, and not your own local machine , right?

Comment: Yes I'm using cdn, like including a link in my file

Comment: Could you put up a mock on codepen or any of the similar sites?